# Changes made aren't being saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues with saving changes made to data that has been loaded in.  I read in a text file of data, orders that have been made, save it to the database and then check these orders for a specific item.  If the order has this item (for example, bleach), I set the status of the order to Awaiting Approval so a supervisor will look at the order before processing.  My problem is when I load in a file with only a couple of orders, the status of the Order successfully saves as Awaiting Approval, when it finds an Order with bleach.  When the file is large, the changes don't persist and the Status stays as Ready for Payment (the status it is set to when it is first saved).  The code is quite simple,

```
foreach(App_Order currentOrder in Orders)
{
    foreach(App_Item currentItem in currentOrder)
    {
        if(currentItem == bleach) // this is just an example
        {
            currentOrder.Status = 'AwaitingApproval';
            _unitOfWork.Orders.Update(currentOrder);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting a try/Catch around the save to see if it throws any exceptions but none.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is **_unitOfWork** your DataContext ?

Comment: Debug your code, Is _unitOfWork.Save() ever called?

Comment: If it works fine for a small file, there's not really a problem with saving the entity as such, it's probably somewhere else. Did you try placing a breakpoint in here for a large file and see if it hits?

Comment: Yip, _unitOfWork is my DatabaseContext

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't write equal operator, `if(currentItem == bleach)` always returns false. Check the equality by comparing properties.

Example

```
if(currentItem.Status == bleach.Status)
```

Comment: If it works for small amount of orders (small file), then this comparison cannot be the issue.